# Two results in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is the simplified table to ask my question:

```
      Names
+------+----------+
|  id  |   name   |
|------+----------|
|  1   |  Alex    |
|      |          |
|  2   |  John    |
|      |          |
|  3   |  Fred    |
|      |          |
|  4   |  Andy    |
+------+----------+

id: primary key
```

How can I execute just a ***single*** query and fetch two names? I have two  IDs `n1` and `n2` and I want to retrieve two corresponding names:

```
SELECT name1, name2 FROM names WHERE ...n1....n2...
```

After executing the query for `n1=2` and `n2=3` the result should be:

```
+------------+------------+
|   name1    |   name2    |
+------------+------------+
|   John     |   Fred     |
+------------+------------+
```

Is it possible? I have no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straightforward, though has to execute two subselects:

```
SELECT
(SELECT Name FROM Names WHERE ID = 2) as Name1,
(SELECT Name FROM Names WHERE ID = 3) as Name2
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select
  max(case when id = 2 then name end) Name1,
  max(case when id = 3 then name end) Name2
from names;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90d72/2)

Comment: +1 another way and live test! but is there any point to prefer your code against @Fabian's code?

Comment: @MM. I typically prefer this method and it only queries the table once.

Comment: +1 . . . This is a better solution than the chosen answer because (1) it scans the table only once and (2) it will not return an error if there is more than one row for a given id.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree and disagree. (1): Both results will return almost instantly. (2): It will never return an error if the id is indeed an ID. :) => Not harmful issues, IMHO.

Comment: The query you wrote has search order O(n) due to _max()_ function... but Fabian's query has two searches with order O(Log(n)) since _ID_ is a primary key. And for large tables O(2Log(n)) is better than O(n). So, accepted answer is better. Am I right?

Comment: @MM. The running time really depends on the execution plan that the optimizer chooses. You haven't provided the version of MySQL you are using, so we can't know really. If you have tested in your version that Fabian's query is consistently faster, then use that. You haven't either declared whether there is an index on `ID` (not to mention unique.) We could guess that from the data provided but really, there are so many strange designs published at SO, that nothing looks weird after a while.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT (SELECT Name FROM names WHERE ID =1 ), (SELECT Name FROM Names WHERE ID = 2) FROM DUAL

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub select :
    SELECT (SELECT `name` FROM `Names` WHERE `id`=1) AS `name1`, (SELECT `name` FROM `Names` WHERE `id`=2) AS `name2`

Answer (score 0):

mm i hoped i understand seems simple  :

```
SELECT `name` FROM `names` WHERE `id` = '1' OR `id` = '2' LIMIT 2
```

Comment: No no! It will select ONE name which has id=1 and id=2 which is impossible. So, the result is null.

Comment: changed the AND to OR was mistake.

Comment: Still it returns just one name, but I need two.

Comment: I need two columns, you're getting two rows.